# Bitbucket with ssh : git push OK but git clone KO. HTTPS works fine

Tags: linux, ssh, git

My company has a bitbucket server hosting git repos.
On my machine, `https` works fine and I can clone/pull/push repos whenever I have R/W access.

I added ssh credentials to bitbucket to use ssh (easier use once set up).

Using the ssh address, I'm able to pull and push my repo using ssh but **I can't clone the same repo to get a second local copy (Permission denied).**

Moreover, whenever I clone the exact same repo using https (it works), change the remote to ssh, then try to push using ssh, I get the same `Permission denied` error.

I don't know how the first local repo instance was cloned, nor why it's able to pull/push whereas the second instance can't.

I used `git config -l` to check whether both repos had different config, but they don't (once the https-cloned repo has the ssh remote set up). Both have the same config but different behaviour...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a company hosted BitBucket, I would suggest that you went to the team who is responsible for help. There could be any number of things they have changed which could cause this.